# Not Found - Exception in OCaml

Tags: exception, mapping, ocaml

I'm trying to check a mapping I've made to see if there are any values that match the word I'm sending. But it should return zero when there are no instances found. Instead, it's throwing `Exception: Not_found.` and exiting.

Is there any way I can catch this error? I thought Some and None were supposed to do the trick.

```
let word_count word =
            match DictMap.find word word_mapping with
            | None -> 0
            | Some count -> count;;
```

Comment: You can catch exceptions with `try/with` https://www.google.com/search?q=ocaml+exception+handling&oq=ocaml+exception+handling&aqs=chrome..69i57.3703j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You use the non-standard function `DictMap.find` – who can help you if you do not give the specification of this function or its implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `DictMap` is some result of applying [the `Map` functor](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html).  Use `try`-`with` (rather than the `option` type) since [`find`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.Make.html#VALfind) raises an exception rather than returning `None` when the key is not found.

```
let word_count word = try DictMap.find word word_mapping with Not_found -> 0;;
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it raised an exception as opposed to moving through my match cases.